# how to use compound index in mongodb using java/scala

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, mongodb-java, mongodb-java-3.3.0

I want to create an index on both fields `a` and `b` but I want the `b` field to be unique only I am not sure how can I achieve this in using compound index please help here is the code

```
var index=collectionMongo("test").createIndex(new BasicDBObject("a", 1))

var index1=collectionMongo("test").createIndex(new BasicDBObject("b", 1),new BasicDBObject("unique", true))
```

how can i perform my desired task in a compound index please help

Comment: I think you can  only set the compound index as unique, not by field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I look at it, you're already doing it right since [index intersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-intersection/) should handle the compound index for you. You've created an index for `a` and a unique index for `b` and mongo will use both of them when you perform a query that accepts both the fields.

You can check out if the index is properly utilized by running `db.find({"query involving a and b here"}).explain("executionStats")`

Intersection indexes may be favourable to a compound index if you need to index many fields (single and compounded) since it reduces the disk space needed as a whole.